# Hibernate do not update de path to search hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, configuration

I've tried to indicate a  relative path to hibernate get the hibernate.cfg.xml but it does not work, because I've wrote that wrong (i've typed cgf instead of cfg in the file's name). So I've tried an absolute path but Hibernate doesn't recognize the new path, and still looking at the relative path that I've passed before. But the parameter .configure() has chenged, why does Hibernate ignore and insists in mistake?

My code:

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        //  Use the mappings and properties specified in an application resource named hibernate.cfg.xml.
        configuration.configure("C:\\Users\\Lucas_Pletsch\\eclipse-workspace\\PDV\\main\\resources\\hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

The error screen showing that Hibernate searched for hibernate.cfg.xml in the path that I've passed as parameter before:

[image]

Now I've tried this:

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

And the error message have changed, but Hibernate still not finding .cfg.xml:

[image]

Comment: Check your Deployment Assembly source folder. or Update maven project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your maven project: RightClick > Maven > Update Project.

If issue still persists place hibernate.cfg.xml file under the src folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your hibernate.cfg.xml file is already part of classpath. you don't need to specify complete path

Try below code :

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                    "hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Ok, i've made the changes, but Hibernate still don't find the cfg. Look at my question, I've added the new printscreen

Answer (score 1):

Update your project as: Right click on the project->select Maven->then select Update project